# Elastic Search - How to Query against a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm attempting to use Elastic Search in a rails application. I have one table named "comments" and the following query correctly searches for multiple words:

```
def self.search(query, id)
    #puts id
    #puts query
  __elasticsearch__.search(
    {
      query: {
        multi_match: {
        query: query,

        #query: { query: {
        #   query: "*query* and thread_id:id"
        #}},

          fields: ['title^10', 'body']
        }   
      }
    }
  )
end
```

In the table I have another column "thread_id" and I'd like to limit the search I already have to a specific thread_id.

I've tried the commented out code (see above), but I'm obviously missing something basic in the ES select.

I think it's either that my indexing of comments isn't including the thread_id or the syntax is just wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from ES ver 2.x you need to make bool query with filter clause. Before 2.x you need to use filter query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still a little fuzzy on the syntax. I'm using the latest ES and rails 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone out there who needs the syntax for this, here's the answer (at least this worked for me):

```
def self.search(q, id = nil)
  __elasticsearch__.search(
    {
        query: {
            multi_match: {
                query: q,
                fields: [ "title^10", "body" ]
            }
        },
        filter: {
            term: {thread_id: id}
        }
    }
  )
end
```